# Extracting one value from array into a variable - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I know that maybe i will sound stupid for some people , but i am trying to extract single value from my array and insert it into a variable . How was possible to do it . In my case i want to have a new variable with the value only of the `fileId`

```
const arrayOfFiles = rowData.files;
```

**Output :**

```
[{…}, {…}]
0: {fileId: 166, fileExtension: "CSV"}
1: {fileId: 167, fileExtension: "XLSX"}
lastIndex: (...)
lastItem: (...)
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**Tryout**

```
 arrayOfFiles.forEach(file=> console.log(file.fileId));
```

**Output**

```
166
167
```

But how can i insert this value into a single variable ? 
I gave a try something like this :

```
const fileId = arrayOfFiles.forEach((file) => file.fileId);
```

But it returns me `undefined` . Any suggestions what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: What value do you expect `fileId` to have? `166` or `167`? Or maybe an array with both? Or is that not what you're asking?

Comment: Basically `const fileId` should be equal to `file.fileId` , because on click i can detect which id is requested

Answer (score 1):

```
const arrayOfFiles = [{fileId: 166, fileExtension: "CSV"}, {fileId: 167, fileExtension: "XLSX"}];
var ids = arrayOfFiles.map((file) => file.fileId);
console.log(ids)
```

Comment: Not exactly . I am not expecting new arrays of `files.fileId`

Comment: What you are expecting? I thought you want - **how can i insert this value into a single variable ?**

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the forEach, unlike map, filter, reduce, find, etc.. it doesn't return any value, hence you're getting undefined.

```
const res = arrayOfFiles.forEach(file => file.fileId); // undefined

const res = arrayOfFiles.map(file => file.fileId); // [166, 167]

const res = arrayOfFiles.filter(file => file.fileId === 166); // [166]

const res = arrayOfFiles.find(file => file.fileId === 166); // 166
```